# Servlet Filter as Component Spring Boot

Tags: spring, configuration, spring-boot, components, servlet-filters

I would like to configure Servlet Filter in a Spring Boot Web Application and I would like to autowire some Beans and properties using @Value annotation. I was able to achieve this using following configurations :

```
   @Configuration
   public class MyWebConfig{  
      @Autowire
      MyFilter filter;

      @Autowire
      MyAnotherFilter anotherFilter;  

      @Bean
      public FilterRegistrationBean someFilterRegistration() {
           FilterRegistrationBean registration = new  FilterRegistrationBean();
           registration.setFilter(filter);
           registration.setOrder(1);
           return registration;
      }

      @Bean
      public FilterRegistrationBean someFilterRegistration() {
           FilterRegistrationBean registration = new  FilterRegistrationBean();
           registration.setFilter(anotherFilter);
           registration.setOrder(2);
           return registration;
      }

   }
```

And I have configured both the filters (showing just one filter for brevity):

```
@Configuration
public class MyFilter implements Filter{

   @Value("${my.property.key}")
   private String myProperty;

   public void doFilter(...){
        ....
   }

   //init and destroy stubs  
        ....    
}
```

Everything works fine. Still I have few questions :
    1) It works even when I comment out FilterRegistrationBean piece of code. I feel I must use FilterRegistrationBean if I want to set certain order. Correct?
    2) Is there any way I can set order or other configuration like url patterns without FilterRegistrationBean?
   3) I believe I can use @Component can replace @Configuration annotation on Filter class and it will work correctly?
   4) And finally Is it good to have Filter class itself marked as @Component/@Configuration?

Please note that I am using @SpringBootApplication over Main application class.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> 1) It works even when I comment out FilterRegistrationBean piece of code. I feel I must use FilterRegistrationBean if I want to set certain order. Correct?

It works because any `Filter` beans are automatically registered with some default configuration unless you've provided an explicit registration bean.

> 2) Is there any way I can set order or other configuration like url patterns without FilterRegistrationBean?

You can set the order by using `@Order` on your `Filter` or having it implement `Ordered`.

You should use a registration bean if you want to set the URL pattern

> 3) I believe I can use @Component can replace @Configuration annotation on Filter class and it will work correctly?

Correct. Your filter isn't configuration so it should be annotated with `@Component` rather than `@Configuration`

> 4) And finally Is it good to have Filter class itself marked as @Component/@Configuration?

Yes, it's fine to annotate a Filter with `@Component`. The alternative would be to use a `@Bean` method on a `@Configuration` class.