# accessing @Value inside custom spring boot filter

Tags: spring-boot, filter

I have a spring boot filter mentioned below. I want to access a properties.file value in this filter. @Value seems to be not giving null value.
I have seen previous answers where they have mentioned that filter is not part of spring boot context that is why @Value annotated field is not readable.
But I am not able to find a correct implementation that how can access @Value inside filter.

```
@Component
public class SecurityAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {



    @Value("${test.client}")
private String appClient;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // custom logic

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Is there any way in which values from properties file can be picked up inside a filter via @Value

Comment: "filter is not part of spring boot context", we have overcome that by `@Component`, now can use `@Value` [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37890242/592355)

Answer (score 1):

In theory , there should not be any differences to inject the value from the properties file as long as they are defined as spring bean.

So assuming that your `SecurityAuthenticationFilter` can be successfully registered as a spring bean, the properties can be injected into it by :

```java
@Component
public class SecurityAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Value("${foobar.config1}")
    private String config1;
    
    @Value("${foobar.config2}")
    private String config2;
  

}
```

If it does not work in your case , it is more related to other configuration problem rather than `@Value` , which you need to provide me more information to figure out why it does not work.

Comment: I have gone through this reference where they have mentioned this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62672756/properties-in-application-properties-not-getting-loaded-in-filter-class

Comment: there is no other configuration that I am performing. I h=just want to read properties file value via @Value inside a filter

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by 2 ways:

- Create bean that will store your data from properies file (pretty good when you have lot of properties):

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "prefix")
public class ConfigProperties {
    
    private String val1;
    private int val2;
    private String val3;

    // standard getters and setters
}
```

this will read properties like:
prefix.val1, prefix.val2 and prefix.val3
note that setters are mandatory (to incject values)
this object may be incjeted to any component, to get values from this simply use getters

- Inject values as class values like:

```java
@Component
public class SecurityAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Value("${prefix.val1}")
    private String val1;

    @Value("${prefix.val2}")
    private String val2;

    @Value("${prefix.val3}")
    private String val3;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        doSomething(val1, val2);

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate the first way, I am not able to get that

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot here is an article

Comment: I have already tried the @Value. After this only I am saying this is giving null value. value is not getting picked from application.properties file.

Comment: Can u paste your application.properties file?